# Fitter Nearest-Neighbor function with three nested loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, combinatorics

**Background Problem**

Consider a set of students that we want to place into `Ng` groups each of which contains `Ns` students.  Let's label the students 1, 2, ... , Ng * Ns, and let an **assignment** of students be an array of shape (Ng, Ns) that encodes the groupings of students.  For example, if Ng = 2 and Ns = 3, then an assignment of students could be:

[[1, 4, 5], [2, 3, 6]]

note that any assignment that differs either in permuting students within groups, or in permuting the groups themselves would be considered an **equivalent** assignment.  So for the assignment above, one equivalent assignment would be:

[[6, 3, 2], [1, 5, 4]]

For a given assignment A, we define a **neighboring assignment** as any inequivalent assignment that differs from A by a single swap of students.  For example, a neighbor of the first assignment above is obtained by swapping students 1 and 6 to obtain

[[1, 3, 2], [6, 5, 4]]

Additionally, we have a **fitness function** `f` that takes an assignment `A` as its input, and outputs a real number f(A).  The goal is to construct a function which I call `fitter_neighbor` which takes an assignment A and a fitness function f as its inputs and returns a fitter neighboring assignment provided such an assignment exists.  If no such assignment exists, then `fitter_neighbor` should return A.  It is not required that `fitter_neighbor` returns the fittest neighbor, and in fact, the goal is to have it systematically search through the neighbors and return the first fitter neighbor it comes across.

**Current seemingly-not-very-pythonic code**

```
def fitter_neighbor(A, f):

    Ng = len(A) #number of groups
    Ns = len(A[0]) #number of students per group
    Nn = int(Ns ** 2 * Ng * (Ng - 1) / 2) #number of neighboring assignments

    A_swap = np.copy(A) #initialize copy of assignment to be changed

    g1 = 0 #group number of person A in swap
    n_swaps = 0 #counter for number of swaps considered

    while g1 < Ng and f(A_swap) <= f(A) and n_swaps < Nn:
        s1 = 0
        while s1 < Ns and f(A_swap) <= f(A) and n_swaps < Nn:
            g2 = g1 + 1 #ensures that no swaps are repeated
            while g2 < Ng and f(A_swap) <= f(A) and n_swaps < Nn:
                s2 = 0
                while s2 < Ns and f(A_swap) <= f(A) and n_swaps < Nn:
                    A_swap = np.copy(A)
                    A_swap[g1, s1], A_swap[g2, s2] = A_swap[g2, s2], A_swap[g1, s1]
                    n_swaps += 1
                    s2 += 1
                g2 += 1    
            s1 += 1
        g1 += 1 
    if n_swaps < Nn:
        return A_swap
    else:
        return A
```

Can `fitter_neighbor` be  written in a more pythonic way?  In particular, is it possible to eliminate the nested while loops in some clever way?

As an example fitness function for the case Ns = 2, consider

```
def f2(A):
    return np.sum([(g[1] - g[0]) ** 2 for g in A])
```

Comment: I thinking doing something with sets, will have a look at it today.

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen Yeah I agree that would seems more appropriate since ordering within groups and ordering of groups doesn't matter here.  Perhaps it will facilitate getting rid of some nested loops.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution but a line of thought you may use for implementation. You can define the group of students as sets and then make tuples of these sets, so for example `({1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6})`, let's call this tuple A and another tuple of sets B: `(1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 6})` I assume here that the order of the sets is important as you want to compare the first set of A with the first set of B, and so on...

You can then compare these tuples of sets by:

```
A = ({1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}, {8, 10, 12})
B = ({1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 6}, {8, 10, 12})
C = []
D = []

for i, a_list in enumerate(A):
   for j, b_list in enumerate(B):
       if i == j:
           C.append(a_list - b_list)
           D.append(b_list - a_list)

C = tuple(C)
D = tuple(D)
print(f'A: {A}\nB: {B}\nC: {C}\nD: {D}')
```

Answer:

```
A: ({1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}, {8, 10, 12})
B: ({1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 6}, {8, 10, 12})
C: ({3}, {4}, set())
D: ({4}, {3}, set())
```

C and D are then tuples with sets of differences for the first set, second set, etc. If these include sets with one element you know the sets in A and B are the same except for that one element.

Comment: Hmmm can you elaborate on how this might help eliminate the nested while loops?

Comment: as mentioned this is not a solution, but a avenue you may try to get one. Appreciate if can you give me the definition/ code of the function f(A) to dig deeper in the program, so I can run your code myself. Thanks.

Comment: Sure.  I included a random example of one in the text of the question.